# layout-ldrtl forces paddingEnd and PaddingRight instead of PaddingLeft

Tags: android, layout, padding, right-to-left

My app supports Android API < 17

I have this layout under `layout-ldrtl`

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <TextView
      android:layoutDirection="rtl"
      android:id="@+id/account_name"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right|start"
      android:paddingEnd="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size_plus_margin"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size_plus_margin"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:lines="1"/>
</merge>
```

and this layout:

```
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/account_name"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left|start"
      android:paddingEnd="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size_plus_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size_plus_margin"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:lines="1"/>
```

but i get a warning paddingEnd should be accompanied with PaddingRight.

But i have added PaddingLeft as End = Left int rtl.

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`End` is the same as `Right` (in default left to right layout).

`Start` matches with `Left`

The lint warning it is giving you is telling you to try and keep things symmetrical, so RTL layouts look the same as LTR

In other words - if you are supplying End, also supply Start and if you are supplying Right (which you are, to support older version) then also supply Left

...or just ignore it. It's definitely not critical

Comment: yes, but in rtl I want to set the mirror padding so I keep `PaddingEnd` in both. but it will be once `right` and other `left`.no?

Comment: Yes. I find this lint warning unhelpful myself.